# How we redirect to other pages in WordPress?

Tags: wp-redirect

I am using an `onclick` function to redirect the user if they are not login.

I am calling a php function in achor tag like this

```
<a href="#" class="fright hrtacnhor" onclick="<?php checkstatus(); ?>">save to my favorite</a>
```

and the function I am using is

```
<?php
function checkstatus(){
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 8 ) );exit; 
}
?>
```

But the problem is that when i click it not call the fucntion. I also try to use `wp_redirect()` function directly in `onclick` but it not working so any one please guide me how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the redirect by means of JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" class="fright hrtacnhor" onclick="window.location='<?php echo get_permalink( 8 ) ?>'">save to my favorite</a>
```

But why yould you want to do it that way and not just use the link directly?

Comment: Because when any user `click` on it. Div flip and store some data related to that post. So for this purpose user have to login first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP this way.

PHP is static and will is parsed when the output is generated. When the page is viewed PHP can't be called directly anymore. Please [read the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) of PHP about this.

In this case (I guess you simply want to get the visitor on the other page) you can put the `get_permalink()` directly in the `href` property:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 8 ); ?>" class="fright hrtacnhor">save to my favorite</a>
```

Or, if you want to use JavaScript (by the answer of **t f**):

```
<a href="#" class="fright hrtacnhor" onclick="javascript:window.location='<?php echo get_permalink( 8 ); ?>';">save to my favorite</a>
```